# Print function not working in a Arduino code in Python

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-uno

I have this code that runs on an Arduino board and it is written in Python but I do not know why it doesn't work. I want that the led turns on and off automatically (that part is correct) but I also want that when it is on, it prints "led on" and when is off it prints "led off". But now it only prints "led on". What is wrong with the code?

```py
from fhict_cb_01.custom_telemetrix import CustomTelemetrix

import time

board = CustomTelemetrix()

board.set_pin_mode_digital_output(5)
def print_numbers():
    while True:  
        board.digital_write(5,1) 
        time.sleep(1) 
        board.digital_write(5,0) 
        time.sleep(1) 
        Led_state = board.digital_read(5)    
        if Led_state == 0: 
            print("led off") 
        else: 
            print("led on") 

print_numbers()
```

Comment: Think about a good title for your question. Something is wrong and you don't know why. This is true for about 100% of the questions on this site. If it wasn't wrong, you'd not ask. If you knew why, you'd fix it. [Edit] and write a title that tells the reader what your asking. Thanks.

Comment: You must check for the LED state (and print) it after **each** change of the state.

Answer (score 1):

Problems like this are easily solved by going through the program's code and
seeing how the program's state changes over time. In your function
`print_numbers()` (btw, what numbers?), there's only
one state and that's the on/off state of the LED.

I added some very verbose comments to the source code. In practice, it will often suffice to do this mentally.

```py
def print_numbers():
    while True:                             # loop forever
        board.digital_write(5,1)            # turn LED on
        time.sleep(1)                       # wait for one second
        board.digital_write(5,0)            # turn LED off
        time.sleep(1)                       # wait for one second
        Led_state = board.digital_read(5)   # read on/off state of LED, this will always be off because we turned it off two lines above
        if Led_state == 0:                  # print stuff
            print("led off") 
        else: 
            print("led on")                 
                                            # jump to beginning of loop, start over
```

One way to make the program print the actual LED state would be to query first and
then flip it to the other state:

```py
def print_numbers():
    while True:
        Led_state = board.digital_read(5)
        if Led_state == 0:
            board.digital_write(5, 1)
            print("led on")                 
        else: 
            board.digital_write(5, 0)
            print("led off") 
        time.sleep(1)
```

It could also be done without reading the LED's state at all, keeping your
original unrolled loop:

```py
def print_numbers():
    while True:
        board.digital_write(5, 1)
        print("led on")                 
        time.sleep(1)
        board.digital_write(5, 0)
        print("led off")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you, the one of the query is not working but the one without a loop does. Already changed the question by the way.

Comment: All of the functions do have a loop. Sorry to have posted something that apparently doesn't work. I'll try and fix it. In the mean time, I'd be grateful for more information.

Comment: sorry, I mean the one without if statements. I am using arduino uno connected to a richshield for your information, maybe it has something to do with it. I sincerely don't know.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't have an Arduino (or any experience with it). I double-checked the code. The only source of failure might be that `board.digital_read(5)` does not return the LED's state. Maybe you could `print` its result to make sure.